# Encoding / Decoding Fingerprint with Python

Tags: python, bech32

We currently use a python script to get fingerprints from assetName and policy id. However we are resorting to using the cardano bech32 binary for the final part of the process.

```
from hashlib import blake2b
from subprocess import check_output
import binascii
import bech32
import sys

policyId = '60a75d4bfee53ebe583679faed1fba8a8921abfd685dbc76e313032a'
tokenId = '416433763173446576696c7331313739'
binary_asset = binascii.unhexlify(policyId + tokenId)
output = blake2b(binary_asset, digest_size=20).hexdigest()
output = check_output([f"/home/bech32bin/bech32.sh", str(output)]).decode(sys.stdout.encoding).strip()

print(output)

### output is asset1rgafp0kmehn9ws6g9224fyjd550wakdhlupk0k (correct)
```

Where the contents of bech32.sh are:

```
/home/bech32bin/bech32 asset <<< $1
```

This utilises the bech32 binary for the final stage of the process detailed in pseudocode here https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip14/

Does anyone have an idea for a pythonic method of doing the last part. Without having to call a subprocess (which is slow, especially when looping through on potentially thousands of nfts) I assume with pythons inbuilt bech32 lib but have been unable to replicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By last part I assume you mean just the `bech32.sh`. If so, you can use the below :

```
encodedstr=bech32.bech32_encode("prefix",bech32.convertbits(bytes.fromhex(hexstr), 8, 5))
```

Comment: perfect. TY mate.